# Is this operator $A = \pmatrix{1&1\\0&1}$ self-adjoint?

Tags: matrices, operator-theory, adjoint-operators

Is this operator
$$A = \pmatrix{1&1\\0&1}$$
self-adjoint? I think not, because
$$\pmatrix{1&1\\0&1}^T\neq A$$
where $T$ is the transposition of the matrix. What do you all think?

Comment: I think it is safe to say that "self-adjoint" with no mention of a quadratic form means the usual quadratic form.  And when we ask something about an "operator" but it is shown as a matrix, we assume it is asked about the linear transformation associated to that matrix in the usual way.  And when it is not specified what field the entries are in, we assume the reals.  And so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming this is an operator on $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the standard inner product $\left< x, y \right> = x \cdot y$, then yes, this is the correct reasoning.

In general, you need to specify an inner product to know if an operator is self-adjoint, because self-adjointness means $\left< x, A y \right> = \left< A x, y \right>$.

In this case, notice that $\left< x, A y \right> = x^T A y$ whilst $\left< A x, y \right> = (Ax)^T y = x^T A^T y$. Consequently one needs $A = A^T$.

Answer (score 3):

No, the operator is not self adjoint.  Your reasoning is correct.

Note that the definition of the adjoint of an operator is *not* simply that the adjoint of $A$ is $A^T$.  However, in the context of real matrices taken with respect to the standard dot product or with respect to the standard dual basis, this is what "adjoint" comes to mean.  An operator is "self-adjoint" if it is equal to its adjoint, which for real matrices means that $A = A^T$.

Comment: It depends on which quadratic form.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom - that wasn't Bernard's point; he was referring to the fact that the self-adjointness of an **operator** is defined with respect to a given quadratic form.

Comment: @Surb that's one of two definitions

Comment: @Surb the more useful thing to say here is that *whatever* the definition of self-adjoint happens to be in this context, it suffices to check whether $A = A^T$.  A link to a proof of *this* fact might then be helpful.

Comment: @Surb I also wouldn't be surprised if OP is in a context where he/she is simply taught that "adjoint" means "transpose", especially given the nature of the question.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, for any scalar product, $A$ is never self-adjoint. Let $f$ be a non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $M=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\b&c\end{pmatrix}$ be its matrix in the canonical basis. The adjoint $\tilde{A}$ of $A$ is defined by $f(x,\tilde{A}y)=f(Ax,y)$, that is $M\tilde{A}=A^TM$. Thus $A$ is self-adjoint iff $MA=A^TM$. We obtain the following conditions on $M$: $a=0,b\not= 0$, and $f$ cannot be positive.

EDIT. We prove the PROPOSITION (valid for any $n$): Let $A\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$. There is a scalar product $f$ s.t. $A$ is self-adjoint with respect to $f$ $\iff$ $A$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{R}$.

PROOF. ($\Rightarrow$) According to Andreas's comment below, if $A$ is $M$-self-adjoint, then $A$ can be diagonalized with a $M$-orthogonal matrix $U$ (it satisfies $f(x,y)=f(Ux,Uy)$ that is $M=U^TMU$).

($\Leftarrow$) There is an invertible $P$ s.t. $A=PDP^{-1}$ where $D$ is diagonal. Let $\Delta$ be a positive diagonal matrix and $M=P^{-T}\Delta P^{-1}$; note that $M$ is symmetric $>0$. Clearly $MA=A^TM$ and we are done.

Comment: Another way to see that no scalar product can make $A$ self-adjoint is to notice that both of its eigenvalues are $1$ yet $A$ is not the identity matrix.

Comment: Can we make $A$ self-adjoint if we allow our inner product to be indefinite?  Can we do this for any matrix?  To avoid trivial cases, let's require the inner product to be non-degenerate as well.

Comment: @ Michael Seifert , an inner product is associated (for me) to a positive quadratic form.